# Problem installing Help of Delphi (2009 and/or XE)

Tags: delphi, installation

I want to install Delphi documentation or either 2OO9 or XE.
But I receive this message : Namespace not found on this PC ...

See the log file (debug enabled) : http://www.mediafire.com/file/2p31yh76kzt1spb/H2Reg_Log.txt

What's the solution ?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This probably means your installation is corrupt. Try uninstalling and then re-installing.

Comment: I done this, but ant result. I had also the problem with D2009, but only on Windows 7, never on XP.